# Vuetify - using change event assign the selected item to a data property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a v-select that looks like this:

```js
    <v-select
      v-model="editedItem.site_id"
      :items="sites"
      label="Sites"
      item-text="name"
      item-value="id"
    ></v-select>
```

The sites items look like this:

```
0:
    city: (...)
    client: Object
        created_at: "2020-08-20T11:11:12.000000Z"
        created_by: "..."
        deleted_at: null
        id: 1
        name: "Lemmer"
        updated_at: "2020-08-24T03:53:39.000000Z"
        updated_by: "..."
    client_id: (...)
    country: (...)
    country_id: (...)
    created_at: (...)
    created_by: (...)
    deleted_at: (...)
    id: (...)
    name: (...)
    office: (...)
    street: (...)
    updated_at: (...)
    updated_by: (...)
    zipcode: (...)
```

So now I want to put the on a `@change` event the `sites.client.name` in the var.
What is here the best way?

I tried this:

```
<v-select
  v-model="editedItem.site_id"
  :items="sites"
  label="Sites"
  item-text="name"
  item-value="id"
  @change="clientname = sites.client.name"
></v-select>
```

But I get the this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
```

Comment: do you want to assign the selected value to `clientName`?

Comment: no. I want from the item that is selected the client.name save into clientname

Comment: did you check my edited answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you cannot use site.name because if you make item-value="id", site value will be the same as id.
I made a simple codepen for your issue.
Please reference it. https://codepen.io/plsdev89/pen/OJNpmyG

```
<label>Client name: {{clientname}}</label>
<v-select
   :items="sites"
   label="Sites"
   item-text="name"
   item-value="id"
   @change="handleSiteChange"
 ></v-select>
...
handleSiteChange(id) {
  let site = this.sites.filter(item => item.id === id);
  if(site.length > 0) {
    this.clientname = site[0].name;
  }
}
```